# R ggplot2 Forecast Date Format

Tags: r

Having a tough time getting the x-axis on a forecast autoplot (ggplot) to display the dates as `"%m/%d/%y"` instead of a decimal format.  I found a solution that added `+ scale_x_date(labels = format("%m/%d/%y"))` onto the ggplot but that is giving me errors for an already present x-axis as well as invalid input. This seems like it should be as simple as converting the decimal format to a date, because it seems like a lot more work to build an entire x-axis from scratch.

Here is my code:

```
  library(forecast)
  library(lubridate)
  library(ggplot2)
  library(ggfortify)
  library(scales)


  ActualDemand <- c(250, 800 , 500, 4000)
  STRING_DATE <- c("05/13/2017","05/06/2017", "5/20/2017", "05/27/2017")

  dataset <- data.frame(ActualDemand, STRING_DATE)

  #convert from string to date
  dataset$STRING_DATE = lubridate::mdy(dataset$STRING_DATE)
  dataRowCount <- nrow(dataset)

  #find start date
  startDate <- NULL

  for (i in 1:dataRowCount) {
    if (i == 1) {
      startDate <- dataset[i, 2]
      next
    }

    compareDate <- dataset[i,2]

    if (compareDate < startDate) {
      startDate <- compareDate
    } else {
      next
    }
  }

  #transformed set
  datasetSorted <- dataset[order(dataset$STRING_DATE),]

  #build time series, run outlier detection
  ts <- ts(datasetSorted$ActualDemand, frequency = 52, start = c(year(startDate), week(startDate)))
  print(week(startDate))
  cleaned_ts <- tsclean(ts)

  #forecast algorithm
  tbat_model <- tbats(cleaned_ts)
  tbat_forecast <- forecast(tbat_model, h=26)

  autoplot(tbat_forecast)
```

Here is the chart, which is interpreting the dates but displaying them as decimals:

[image]

FYI this is some quick sample data, actual data is coming from a PowerBI dynamic dataframe.

Answer (score 3):

Hope you have solved it earlier. If not (and for others), I have been trying to figure out the same issue myself for last couple of hours, so here is my solution:

Just modifying last lines of your code into:

```
my_date_transform <- function(x) {format(date_decimal(x), "%m/%d/%y")}
autoplot(tbat_forecast)+
  scale_x_continuous(labels = my_date_transform)
```

gives you the following result:
[final_graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvtF6.png).